# Create Mock objects from XML

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, moq, rhino-mocks

Is it possible using Mock Framework to create and return object based on XML data file

```
var onlineUser = new Mock<IOnlineUser>();
onlineUser.Setup(o => o.UserIdentity).Returns(person);
```

the person object should be constructed using XML data

Comment: Not unless you code it yourself. Moq doesn't have any XML features, which is a good thing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Assuming above is service call return. 
I have the service ready with response but I want to write a unit test which will mock the service and return static response reading from xml

Comment: Why not just define the response in code? That enables you to keep the test logic and data together instead of having them two separate places. That would be better for maintainability.